# I am unable to mount my previous btrfs RAID 1 home directory on reinstall of Ubuntu server 14.04 (was using 14.10)

Tags: server, mount, raid, btrfs

**Update 2**

I mounted as degraded to /home and something interesting happened:

```
jake@DAVYJONES:~$ sudo mount -o degraded /dev/sdb1 /home
jake@DAVYJONES:~$ sudo btrfs fi show
Label: Home  uuid: 3673d0b0-6bfc-4a55-a6d1-69fa30b8c4af
    Total devices 5 FS bytes used 6.15TiB
    devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 4.15TiB path /dev/sdb1
    devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 1.42TiB path /dev/sde
    devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 1.42TiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 1.42TiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    5 size 5.46TiB used 4.15TiB path

Btrfs v3.12
```

My 5th disk is there, but has no `/dev/sd*` assigned to it, I think that may be one of the missing pieces here.  Then I need to keep this btrfs filesystem persistently assigned to /home, which i assume I can do by fstab, or just reinstall again and assign (ran into issues when trying this today so I skipped that part).  Does anyone have an idea on how to get this assigned correctly?  I could not find anything on this by searching around.

**Update**

One issue I was having was no btrfs-tools installed, i now have it installed but cannot mount my drives, what am i doing wrong?  The end goal is to have this mounted as /home, and to add my 5th drive back in:

```
Jake@DAVYJONES:~$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
Label: 'Home'  uuid: 3673d0b0-6bfc-4a55-a6d1-69fa30b8c4af
    Total devices 5 FS bytes used 6.15TiB
    devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 4.15TiB path /dev/sdb1
    devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 1.42TiB path /dev/sde
    devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 1.42TiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 1.42TiB path /dev/sdd
    *** Some devices missing

Btrfs v3.12
jake@DAVYJONES:~$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: only root can do that
jake@DAVYJONES:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

**Original**

I am a noob with ubuntu, but pretty good with computers overall, and comfortable (though not well versed) in using command line.

I had successfully been running my home server with Ubuntu for the past several months.  Decided to use BTRFS when I set it up so I could have easy expansion when i want to increase the size of my disks.

Recently after a reboot I had issues with samba to my desktop.  I also had issues logging in through putty, it seemed pretty sporadic, and I could not find the issue.  I figured a fresh install would help rule out an update gone wrong on the system, so I reinstalled 14.10. This is what started me down this path to my current question: how can I add my previous 5-disk btrfs raid 1 partition to a fresh install of ubuntu server?

I could not mount the drives using command line (could someone help explain what the correct procedure is? I was getting a 'btrfs not found' when i tried using 'mount' as used in the link below).  Then i tried setting up fstab per the instructions [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices), and that did not work either.  When i used the fstab route, i got errors about not being able to mount /home and ubuntu would not boot up.  When i removed the line I added to fstab with recovery mode, I was able to boot up and log in with putty again, but of course, my previous home files were not accessible because they were not mounted.

Some additional information: I received a 6TB drive to replace a 1TB in my array over Christmas and did so successfully, including a full balance.  My array consists now of (2) 6TB drives and (3) 3TB drives in Raid 1.  The OS is on a SSD separate.

I suspect something may be physically wrong one of the 6TB drives as when I pulled up the connected drives when trying to mount, one of the 6TB showed no partitions, while the other 4 drives had BTRFS partitions with the name "home"

Any thoughts on how I can get this back up and running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like the command said, your 5th drive is missing.  Either get it working right again, or mount with the `-o degraded` option to proceed without it ( and the redundancy it provided ).

Comment: thank you! I think that got me a little further, I forgot about mounting degraded. See edit 2 above, any idea where to go from here?

Comment: @effectivetechie, I don't know what you are asking now.  If you want to mount it without the 5th disk, then you use the degraded option.  That applies to fstab as well as manually mounting.

Comment: thanks for responding.  I am asking if you (or anyone else) knows why it would appear that my 5th disk is back after mounting in degraded mode.  Did I add it to the array incorrectly? As I see it, that 5th disk should show up with the others when i do a `filesystem show` command, not just after a `mount degraded` command. Does that make sense? Thanks!